# How to solve error "Operator 'getitem' is not supported on this expression" when using case()

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to convert the following SQL into SQLAlchemy:

```
select t1.id, t1.field_A,
    max(case when t2.field_B = 1 then t2.field_C end) test_2_field_b_1,
    max(case when t2.field_B = 2 then t2.field_C end) test_2_field_b_2
from test_1 t1
inner join test_2 t2 on t2.field_A = t1.field_A
group by t1.id, t1.field_A
```

I've got as far as:

```
qry = session.query(
    Test1.id_,
    Test2.field_A,
    func.max(case((Test2.field_B.__eq__(1), "Test2.field_C"))).label("test_2_field_b_1"),
    func.max(case((Test2.field_B.__eq__(2), "Test2.field_C"))).label("test_2_field_b_2"),
)
qry = qry.select_from(Test1)
qry = qry.join(Test2, Test2.field_A.__eq__(Test1.field_A))
qry = qry.group_by(Test1.id_, Test2.field_A)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
NotImplementedError: Operator 'getitem' is not supported on this expression
```

On the line:

```
func.max(case((Test2.field_B.__eq__(1), "Test2.field_C"))).label("test_2_field_b_1"),
```

SO won't let me post the whole traceback as it says there is too much code!

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[case](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=case#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case) takes a *list* of `when` criteria as its first argument, so you need to bracket accordingly:

```
sa.case([(Model.column == value, then_output)])
```

So your code should look like this:

```
qry = session.query(
    Test1.id_,
    Test2.field_A,
    sa.func.max(sa.case([(Test2.field_B == 1, "Test2.field_C")])).label("test_2_field_b_1"),
    sa.func.max(sa.case([(Test2.field_B == 2, "Test2.field_C")])).label("test_2_field_b_2"),
)
qry = qry.select_from(Test1)
qry = qry.join(Test2, Test2.field_A == Test1.field_A)
```

Comment: Awesome thank you!! In the example from the SQLAlchemy site it refers to a list being needed but doesn't actually show it: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case. Note to self - read more carefully next time!